# Passing ID of element to a C# web service (using JSON) from jQuery

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, web-services, listview

I have an  containing a list of divs that jQuery turns into progress bars. On .ready, I build a list of all of these progress bars and for each one, call a webservice that gets a value indicating how full the progress bar should be. In order to do this, I need to pass the ID of the div to the web service.

Because the divs are inside a ListView, I manually set the id to be id="completionbar_<%# Eval("MilestoneID") %>"

However, when I pass this id into my web service, it comes up as "undefined" every time. When I view the source, it looks like it's set correctly.

Here's the jQuery that calls my web service:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".MilestoneCompletion").progressbar({ value: 0 });
    $.each($(".MilestoneCompletion"), function(index, barDiv) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ProjectTracking.aspx/GetText",
            data: "{'id':'" + $(barDiv).id + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            success:
                function(msg) {
                    $(barDiv).progressbar("value", msg.d);
                }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Here's the web service stub that doesn't do anything right now:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static int GetText(string id)
{
    return 75; // returns completion percent
}
```

Here's where I'm setting the id of the div in the ListView:

```
<ItemTemplate>
<li class="ui-widget-content" >
...
<!-- when this div loads, I want to call my webservice -->
<div id="completionbar_<%# Eval("MilestoneID") %>" class="MilestoneCompletion" style="height:30px;"></div>
...
</li></ItemTemplate>
```

I'm thinking maybe the script is executing before the DIV id is set by the ListView databind?

Can I fix this, or is my approach fundamentally flawed?

Comment: I should mention, that this correctly fills each progressbar to 75%.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(barDiv).attr('id')`

Comment: It's a common gotcha. Can't tell you how many times I assumed I could get a `.id` on a jQuery object myself.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it relates to your problem but I believe it should be:

**Update:** you only need to pass in a `function(index)` and then use `this` within the function to reference the div:

```
$(".MilestoneCompletion").each(function(index) {
    ...
    $(this).progressbar("value", msg.d);
```

Comment: Yeah, definitely NOT related to your problem :)